# Помогите с реализацией функции “debug” меню

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Стоит задача, чтобы при 10-ти кратном нажатии на компонент (кнопка) открывалось другая "скрытая" панель. Например как в телеграм (при 10-ти кратном нажатии на профиль в приложении выскакивает дебаг меню). Я пока что новичок и знаю только onClick и onDoubleClick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var button = document.querySelector('#your-button');
var clickCounter = 0;
button.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    // Отменяем действие по умолчанию
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    // Считаем клики
    clickCounter++;

    if (clickCounter === 10) {
        // Показываем твоё меню
        document.querySelector('#your-debag-menu').style.display = 'block';
    }
});
```